# spring security: dot in username on jsp page

Tags: javascript, spring-security, iso-8859-1

I'm using Spring Security 3.1.2.

When username contains dot, following code:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username"/>
```

returns value `user&#46;name` when the username is `user.name`.

It seems that it's ISO 8859-1 character set notation.

Is there any way to convert it to it's usual notation using javascript?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Thats strange, it shouldnt happen i think. I think something else is causing this but im not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication tag does [escaping for HTML](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/taglibs/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/taglibs/authz/AuthenticationTag.java#L51) by default.

You can set the `escapeHtml` attribute to false in the tag if you want to disable this.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute to use is "htmlEscape". For example:

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" htmlEscape="false" />
```